# Replicating Schemaless SOLR Index

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have an index on a Schemaless solr instance. To allow the application to query some of the fields that are in this index, I have to register these fields using the schema REST API http://localhost:8983/solr/schema/fields.

All works fine in isolation. I can also replicate the index to slaves without problem. However, I am unable to query the replicated index using the fields that were registered via the schema REST API.

That means, if I register the field "button" using the API, I can query using this field on master, but I cannot query on slave. I get error message 400 undefined field button.

Now, I also tried to register this field on the slave in the same way I registered it on the master using the schema REST API. This fails with the message: 400 This IndexSchema is not mutable.

Any idea how this should be addressed?

I presume that when the schema is well defined, the schema.xml can be replicated. But what happens with fields created via the REST API?

I am using SOLR 4.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not fully validated that this is the solution to this problem, but my gut feeling tells me that it is. The SOLR master was running SOLR 4.8.0 and the SOLR Slave was running SOLR 4.10.3. It looks like the slave did not completely like the index replicated from 4.8.0. So I downgraded the slave to 4.8.0 and everything works fine.